# Avoiding file corruption issues from a kill

Tags: c, linux

I have a constantly running process (wlescan_dump) whose output is piped to a  program (process_dump). process_dump is an executable written in C, which constantly writes to a file :

```
sudo wlescan_dump | process_dump
```

Now, if I want to programmatically kill the two processes (wlescan_dump and process_dump), how can I do it in a clean way? Will kill -15 to both processes suffice? I am mainly worried about avoiding file corruption, and making sure that pending file writes in process_dump are completed before killing.

Comment: You can catch a `SIGTERM` (signal 15) in your code, and use that to ensure that you properly close any open files before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Kill wlescan_dump and code process_dump to close any open files and quit when stdin is closed.

If you're really paranoid, implement the signal handler larsks suggested and depending on how you use your open files, you could only update them atomically: write to a copy of outputfile, outputfile.temp, and then rename outputfile.temp to outputfile.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `SIGTERM` signal

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_01.html

```
When killing a process or series of processes, it is common sense to start  
trying with the least dangerous signal, SIGTERM. That way, programs that care
about an orderly shutdown get the chance to follow the procedures that they 
have been designed to execute when getting the SIGTERM signal, such as 
cleaning up and closing open files.
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw the comment of larsks explaining exactly the same thing